# Using noquotes function within dplyer runs forever

Tags: r, dplyr, shiny

Hello I am working on a shiny app and I want to arrange my df according to an Input variable. As dplyr demands column names without quotes I am trying to use the noquote function, but for some reason the console runs forever. This is a minimal example:

```
    Server <- function(Input, Output) {
        # loading data sets and bring them to Long Format
        long_data <- read.csv("path")

        x <- paste("This_is_variable", Input$arrange, sep="")
        z <- noquote(x)
        long_data <- long_data %>% arrange(z)
        }
```

I cannot figure out what the problem is. If i use `print(z)` it Returns the variable needed without quotes, but within the arrange command dplyr seems to have problems. If I enter the variable without quotes into arrange it works just fine.

Comment: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html

Comment: I think you should use `long_data <- long_data %>% arrange(!!x)`

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems here.

The first is that anything you do in shiny relying on user input needs to be wrapped in `reactive()` or `observe()` (more often the former). Here you are not doing that.

The second is that it doesn't make sense to try to `arrange()` a data frame on the string "This_is_variablesomething". Instead you want to feed in the variable that is selected by the user.

The last is that you do not use `noquote()` to program using dplyr. You feed a variable using either the tunnel `{{ }}` if you do not provide it in quotes, or you use `.data[[x]]` if you do provide it in quotes. In this case you would use the latter example, using `.data[[input$arrange]]`.

Here's an attempt to address all 3 problems. However, this might not work for you since your example is not reproducible.

```
# Note that you shouldn't put this in the server code, otherwise you will continually reload the data every time the user does something.
    long_data <- read.csv("path")

Server <- function(Input, Output) {

   arranged_df <- reactive({
    arrange(long_data, .data[[input$arrange]])
    # Could also be arrange(long_data, across(input$arrange))
  })

 }
```

Comment: The reason `base::noquote()` doesn't work is that it assigns a "noquote" class attribute to a string, which affects how it is *printed to the console*. It does not change the string into an expression, which is what most dplyr verbs expect. `{{` and `!!` are from the `rlang` package. You can supply strings to verbs directly without additional dependencies using `dplyr::across()`, e.g. `arrange(long_data, across(input$arrange))`

Comment: Thanks @bcarlsen, added `across()` as another option.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use unquoting the `rlang` way i.e:

```r
df<-data.frame(lapply(1:7, function(x) rnorm(100) ))
names(df) <- paste0("This_is_variable", 1:7)
x <-  paste0("This_is_variable", 1) # 1 is the userinput
df %>% arrange(!!x)
```